# A kind of reverse Church-Rosser

Tags: lambda-calculus

In the $\lambda$-calculus.

**Proposition**: For any terms $M$,$N$ such that $M =_\beta N$, there is a term $L$ such that $L \twoheadrightarrow_\beta M$ and $L \twoheadrightarrow_\beta N$.

Is this true or false? A proof sketch or counterexample would be lovely.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried to do to prove or disprove it?

Comment: Not much, asked some people around and no ideas have come where to start. We're not even sure if this is an open question or not.

Comment: It seems like it ought to be possible to find some form that reduces to $M$ in normal order and to $N$ in another order.

Comment: No, that will never work, because it  neglects the assumption that M and N are $\beta$-equivalent, and that assumption is required.

Comment: It won't work in general, since that would imply that that every term is β-equivalent to every term.

Comment: Yes. I had in mind some simple construction that doesn't look at the actual values of $M$ and $N$, and it can't be anything like that.